# How to catch Permission Error with Popen process

Tags: python, popen

This is the error:
Permission Error: Copying of text from this document is not allowed.

I am opening a .exe file on windows. So regular try except block does not seem to catch it. Neither does OSError.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079140/python-subprocess-popen-check-for-success-and-errors#25079374 may be able to help.  You'll have to deal with errors directly from a `subprocess` object.

Comment: I tried subprocess.CalledProcessError
The problem is I want to call Permission Error, I get an error if I do subprocess.CalledProcessError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with the following:

```
try:
    """code here"""
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    """unlock files and try again"""
```

Comment: What ended up being the issue with this method? You said in you were getting an error if you tried this.

Comment: I have no idea really. I do remember getting an error :/ . Anyway it works now, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
exception PermissionError
```

Raised when trying to run an operation without the adequate access rights - for example filesystem permissions. Corresponds to errno EACCES and EPERM.

If you specified irrelevant Exception while trying to catch permission error, I wouldn't be surprised they it is caught

Comment: Doesn't work. It does not seem to catch error. It shows in console in red though.  Anyway to catch it from there?

Comment: Can you share an example code snippet, and what does not work  ?